# Select user position from donations table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table called `donations` that exists every donation of user - like that:

```
uid|month|year|what donate
```

I try to get some `uid` position in this table **but** in specific month and year. this is my code:

```
$table = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT count(*) AS counter FROM donations WHERE uid = ? AND month = ? AND year = ? GROUP BY uid LIMIT 1');
$table->bind_param('iii', $uid, $month, $year);
$table->execute();
$table->bind_result($count);
$table->store_result();
$rows = $table->num_rows;
$table->fetch();
```

The `count` returns my how much times the user donate in the date I choose but not what his position in the `donations` table. anyone see the problem?

Comment: Anyone can help?

Comment: @ Dasmond :- Position means you want sequential list of users according to number of times S/He donates right?

Comment: @ABHI yes you right

Comment: can you share the table column details of donations table.Is uid the primary key of the table?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
SELECT count(*) AS counter 
FROM donations 
WHERE month = '01' AND year = '2019' 
GROUP BY uid
ORDER BY counter desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM (SELECT d.*, (@rn := @rn + 1) as position
      FROM (SELECT uid, COUNT(*) AS num_donations
            FROM donations
            WHERE month = ? AND year = ?
            GROUP BY uid
            ORDER BY num_donations DESC
           ) d CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @rn := 0) params
     ) d
WHERE uid = ?;
```

This does not recognize ties -- it simply orders the values from 1 to n.  Your question is vague on what position means, so this is consistent with what you are asking.

In MySQL 8+, you would simply do:

```
SELECT d.*
FROM (SELECT uid, COUNT(*) AS num_donations,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as position
      FROM donations
      WHERE month = ? AND year = ?
      GROUP BY uid
     ) d
WHERE uid = ?;
```